# Taylor series solution of differential equation

Tags: taylor-expansion

[image][image]
Taylor series expansion and differential equation

Comment: can anyone help me

Comment: Sure: what **exactly** are you having problems with? What have you done so far?

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like a homework question..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: In part 3, how to setup equation?

Comment: What did you get for parts $(1)$ and $(2)$? You should update your question and show your work. What are you stuck on in step 3? You should show your attempts in the body of the question.

Comment: just 2min i uploading my work

Comment: can i anyone tell me? am i doing right

Comment: @AffanAshraf: Your solution is correct. Label steps $1$ through $6$ before turning your assignment in.